# Keep popovercontentsize constant for all views in navigationcontroller

Tags: ios, uipopovercontroller

When I pass my UINavigationController to UIPopOver and set its popOverContentSize property, it remains in effect for only first view. When I navigate to next view, the popOverContent size again expands to full view which is unwanted. How can I restrict the constant size of popOver for all views in navigation controller?

```
- (void)selectTextStyle:(id)sender {
DJTextStyleMasterViewController *textStyle = [[DJTextStyleMasterViewController alloc] init];
self.navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:textStyle];

UIPopoverController *popOver = [[UIPopoverController alloc] 
                                initWithContentViewController:self.navController];
[popOver setDelegate:self];
[popOver setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 400)];
[popOver presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:self.textStyleButton permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];

[textStyle release];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

within the first view controller in the popover controller you could use this method:

```
[self setContentSizeForViewInPopover:CGSizeMake(320, 400)];
```

Then the view of the popover (if it isn't manually modified) should be the same also for the next view controller.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) It worked but needed to be added in other view controllers to resize. Otherwise wont work